# MongoDB Update Concurrently

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.2

I want to update addresses and dependents field concurrently of mongoDb using different API through SpringBoot???

```json
{_id: ObjectId("5effaa5662679b5af2c58829"),
 email: "email@example.com",
 name: {given: "Jesse", family: "Xiao"},
 age: 31,
 addresses: [{label: "home",
              street: "101 Elm Street",
              city: "Springfield",
              state: "CA",
              zip: "90000",
              country: "US"},
             {label: "mom",
              street: "555 Main Street",
              city: "Jonestown",
              province: "Ontario",
              country: "CA"}],
              
dependents: [{label: "wife",
              name: "emily",
              gender: "f",
              },
             {label: "mom",
              name: "joanna",
              gender: "f"}],
            
}
```